# How to remove caret icon from ion-select tag in ionic 2

Tags: ionic2

```html
<ion-select  [interfaceOptions]="{ cssClass: 'popover-wide' }" interface="popover" class="dropdownIcon ci-sec-head ci-mr-15" id="month" [(ngModel)]="calendar.month" (change)="renderCalender()" style="border:transparent; width: 50%;height: 25px;"><!-- <span><img src="../assets/images/dropdown.svg"></span> -->
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let mth of months" [value]="mth.value" [selected]="mth.isSelected">{{mth.text}}</ion-select-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: i am working with ionic 2

Comment: you could directly hide `.select-icon` right?

Comment: Yes i want hide .select-icon

Comment: `ion-select {
  .select-icon {display:none} }`

Comment: already trying this one but not working in my app.  Any other  way?

Comment: difficult to say at this point.. There is no support for ionic 2 anywhere to check. Perhaps time to move to a supported version?

Answer (score 0):

I managed this in Ionic 2 by putting the select in a surrounding div:

```
 <div class="selectWrapper>
     <ion-select...
```

and adding this to the sass file:

```
    .selectWrapper {
       .select-icon {
          visibility: hidden;
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but its not working for me.

Comment: did you add a `!important` to the `visibility`?

Comment: Yes try out with !important still not working in Ionic 2.

Comment: difficult to say at this point.. can you build a sample project and upload it somewhere so I can take a closer look?